# Matplotlib: how to control the plot interval of x axis?

Tags: matplotlib

I'm plotting the `degree of freedom` against the `square error`,:

```
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [0.5,0.6,0.9,0.85],'-')
```

It will produce

[image]

The problem is that ,the x ax is has 0.5 interval, and does not make sense in this context. Because there is simply no 1.5 degree of freedom.

How can I make the x axis into [1,2,3,4,], instead of [1, 1.5, 2, ...]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add directly the positions and the strings you want to put in the x axis. Using your example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [0.5,0.6,0.9,0.85]
plt.plot(x,y,'-')
plt.xticks(list(range(1,max(x)+1)),[str(i) for i in range(1,max(x)+1)])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

, which results in:

[image: x axis with only integers]

Comment: What's the difference between plt.xticks(x)?

Comment: In the recipe plt.xticks() is actually receiving two arguments. The first with the position of the labels (numerical), the second with strings of the labels themselves. You can use both to a lot of control over what happens in the axis. In fact there is a third argument, "rotation" that can be useful as well. See for instance this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184953/specifying-values-for-my-x-axis-using-the-matplotlib-pyplot/36185583#36185583

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the XTick 1 to 4, by 1 `1:1:4` like below

```
plot([1,2,3,4], [0.5,0.6,0.9,0.85],'-');
set(gca,'XTick',1:1:4);
```

or

```
p = plot([1,2,3,4], [0.5,0.6,0.9,0.85],'-');
set(p,'XTick',1:1:4);
```

Comment: Can you give me a more detailed example? it report `name 'gca' is not defined`

Comment: I use `plt.xticks(` instead.

Comment: `plot([1,2,3,4], [0.5,0.6,0.9,0.85],'-')` then `set(gca,'XTick',1:1:4);` Sorry. I would normally leave out the `plt.`, but I like your way better over all.